# Escape character Problems IN MY oBJECT

Tags: javascript

is it possible to create a value with these characteristics with key addBlueborder?

```
var Object = {
    footer: '#footer',
    mockup: '#mockup',
    // My dude??????
    addBlueborder: '"input[name='"+ oBlock +"_fix']"'
 };
```

I don't know to escape with double quote.
I would like to make that:

```
 $(Object.addBlueborder).each(function(e) { ... };
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotes confusion. It should be like this

```
addBlueborder: 'input[name="' + oBlock + '_fix"]'
```

Also note, that quotes around the attribute are not really necessary if your `oBlock` doesn't contain spaces or other weird characters. In this case expression will become even simpler

```
addBlueborder: 'input[name=' + oBlock + '_fix]'
```